Are truffles dirty?
I'm a bit paranoid about eating dirt, so I probably cut away
fruit/vegetable/potato peels/skins more than most people do
(and rinse the final surface more than most people do).
What about truffles?

I'm concerned about the grey "maze edges" in the truffle's core.
What are these?
One source makes me think these are lines of dirt which remain in the nooks and crannies after filamentous growth:

When the spore germinates its forms a singular filamentous cellular structure called a hyphae, this hyphae grows outward branching, forming mycelium. Once it finds another strand of sexually compatible mycelium it exchanges genetic material forming diploid cells and searches for a compatible root structure.

Mushrooms grow in air, not soil, and therefore look safer.  Potatoes, though they grow in soil, grow like a balloon and therefore also look safer.  Do truffles really grow filamentously incorporating the dirt, or do they grow like a balloon pushing out the dirt?
Should I always cook as if there are microbes and bacteria (or any other contaminants) inside a truffle?  Do restaurants usually therefore only serve truffle items which have seen high heat?  Has a typical bottle of gourmet truffle oil from a grocery store seen high heat already?

Which vegetables do you consider "not safe"?

@Luciano For example, an unwashed carrot eaten raw.  In the carrot case I am worried about surface dirt, but the truffle makes me worry further about interior dirt.

What other vegetables (if any) do you believe that have dirt on the inside? Excluding for example leeks or lettuce (the dirt is not inside, it's in between the leaves)

Truffle is super dirty. Please don't eat it. Just give it to me for proper destruction.

eating dirt/being exposed to bacteria is good for the immune system. Less sterile environments are strongly correlated with a lower incidence of allergies. The Amish living on unsterile farms have 50% less allergies than people living in sterile environments inside of the city... TLDR: a little of dirt doesn't hurt and might actually help you.

What do you mean by "dirt"?  Do you mean grains of inorganic rock?  Organic matter?  Bacteria?

You seem to confuse the mycelium and the fruiting body of the truffles.
The part your quote talks about is the mycelium, which (not overly precise, but for this question close enough) can be compared to the roots of other plants. The mycelium is the actual fungus that can survive for a long time and become quite large. At some point, some fungi develop fruiting bodies (sporocarps) (what we colloquially call mushrooms and forage or buy in stores), which contain the spores for reproduction.
We humans and other animals typically consume the fruiting bodies but leave the mycelium alone, not unlike eating the apples, but not gnawing on roots and branches.
When a fruiting body develops, it typically starts from a small point and then expands, often in some closed form to protect the spores while they ripen. If you turn over a champignon, you can see the gills, which is where the spores are. (You could even leave the hat gill-side down on a piece of paper for a few hours and observe the pattern of the released spores.) The underside of an champignon is closed while the mushroom is small and young, only opening up later when it matures. Other mushrooms form some form of sphere that releases the spores at a later time, puffballs are a good example. Truffles are the extreme form of protecting the spores inside the fruiting body. They don’t have the release mechanism, instead they rely upon animals to dig them up and disperse them after consuming the truffles.
This should also allay any fears of eating dirt: Truffles (in the sense of the culinary term, so the dark lumps) will at no point have exposed their inside to the surrounding soil. The only point of contact is the outer skin. The pattern you see in the cross section is the combination of carrier substance and spores.
Restaurants typically scrub the truffles to remove dirt (but cleaning is also done before sale, because buyers are not willing to pay a premium truffle price for adhering dirt), and often will serve truffles raw, shaving them over dishes to preserve their delicate flavor and maximize the taste experience. For your truffle oil, other rules apply, because oil-with-something-in-it needs special measures to prevent botulism, heat treatment is one option.

Can you clarify your term "carrier substance" (which causes the "grey" mazy appearance which is still confusing to me)?  Is it the environment in which the fungus (or the fungus' fruiting body) grows, or is it made entirely by the fungus?  (Sorry if I am being too literal, but it's unclear to me whether something else is "carrying" the fungus or the fungus is "carrying" its fruiting body.)

"not unlike eating the apples, but not gnawing on roots and branches" shoot, that's why I can't digest them!

@bobuhito Imagine a champignon cut in half. There are lighter parts (the “flesh”) and darker parts (the gills with the spores, sometimes the outer skin). All is fungal matter. A truffle (in the sense of the lump sold for consumption) is like the coiled up and entangled version of the same. Or to go back to your original worry: No, it’s not dirt, it’s all mushroom. Mushrooms sometimes encapsulate foreign material like small stones or twigs if they are pressing against them while the fruiting body forms. But you will see that, as it looks completely different.

Hmm, I wish I could see a time-lapse of the fruiting body's growth and how it gets "pumped up" from a few connected hyphae...I'm sure I have some further misunderstandings.

@bobuhito try this video. Just imagine the truffles forming in the soil instead of the champignons on the soil. The principle is the same. You’ll see that it’s pretty much what you describe as “balloon” in your question.

Ah, and “a  few connected hyphae” is just the initial stage of reproduction and growth. If you connect this with the truffle in a store, it’s like wondering how the few unspecific cells after the merge of an egg and a sperm manage to do pole vaulting or become a dynasty. There’s quite a bit of growth and development happening to get from one to the other.

I watched that video, but the white mushroom does not have the grey maze inside...I'm probably too skeptical, but can't help thinking that the grey maze (or maybe people call this "marbling") means that everywhere inside the truffle is gills (and gills have exposure to the dirt).

Of course it doesn’t - the one in the video is a champignon with gills instead of the maze in a truffle. In a truffle, this equivalent of the gills stays  inside and encapsulated all the time. At no point is the inside exposed to soil. And if you watch the video closely, you will see that even these mushrooms grow closed, protecting the spore-carrying part. Only when they want to release the spores, the cap opens and exposes the gills. Truffles don’t have that stage, they have evolved to not opening up, instead relying on animals to distribute the spores after they dug up the tubers.

Thanks, you (finally) had me at "The gills stays inside and encapsulated all the time"! I'm convinced that the inside of truffles is not dirty now.  It's pretty amazing that all of this fruit gets pumped up just through a few skinny hyphae.

You seem to be asking two related questions, one on food safety and one more general question
Raw truffle is considered about as safe as, say, blue cheese
Truffles are safe to eat, raw, for people with a normal immune system and there is no reason to worry about them on those grounds unless you're a pregnant woman, or immunocompromised in some way, due to a presumed possibility of toxoplasmosis contamination in the soil they grow in. In this they are similar to other foods, such as blue cheese, which are fine for people in normal circumstances but carry a very, very low risk of harm to people under certain circumstances, and I cannot find a single food safety agency that advises against the consumption of raw truffles in general. Indeed, raw truffle is routinely used as an ingredient in many restaurants without issue.
This should not be taken as meaning that they can be safely made into oils or incorporated into other products that are intended to be stored. Commercial truffle oils, if they are not simply made with synthetic flavourings, are typically pasteurised to ensure they are safe to eat.
The interior of truffles is inhabited by a variety of microbes
The interior of truffles is home to a variety of bacterial species and these bacteria are believed to be necessary for the production of the characteristic odour of truffles. Like the overwhelming majority of bacteria and microbes found on Earth and in our food, it is likely that these bacteria are completely harmless to humans. There is no health benefit to consuming food that is utterly sterilised and it may even have negative health effects to completely avoid normal exposure to microbes and bacteria, especially in children.

Since the consensus seems to be that dirt is only on the surface of the truffle, I assume the "bacterial species" you mention somehow comes through the hyphae, not from the surrounding dirt.

They are not on the surface, they are in the interior. They will have migrated there from the soil the truffle lives in, or been living with the fungus its whole life.

Note that pregnant women are not immunocompromised, their immune system is working just as well as that of any healthy person. The reason extra care to avoid food poisoning is adviced is that if food poisining happens, the standard treatments (for example a bunch of antibiotika) are not available or at least not recommended to use for pregnant women.

@quarague: Yes, sorry I'll edit the phrasing to make that clearer. Although with toxoplasmosis I believe the concern is that it can cross to the fetus and cause miscarriage in early pregnancy and birth defects later on.

@bobuhito Where a micro-organism comes from isn't particularly relevant; what's relevant is where it can survive, and how it will interact with your body. There are hundreds of different species of bacteria inside your body right now; some are helpful, some neutral, some harmful and hopefully being eliminated by your immune system. Every one had to "arrive" somehow after a sperm and egg fused at the start of your development.
